# Trying to add expressions in azure data factory and getting 'The template function 'dataset' is not defined or not valid.' error

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to add some expressions to my data factory dataset and getting this error:  *The template function 'dataset' is not defined or not valid.'*

I have default value of pipeline parameter:

```
"parameters": {
       "adlFolder": {
                    "type": "String",
                    "defaultValue": "/somePath/"
                },
```

also i have dataset parameters:

```
 "parameters": {
                    "month": {
                        "type": "String",
                        "defaultValue": ""
                    },
                    "date": {
                        "type": "String",
                        "defaultValue": ""
                    },
                    "dest": {
                        "type": "String",
                        "defaultValue": ""
                    }
                },
```

and in the activity output I set expression to this dataset parameters:

```
"parameters": {
                                    "month": "@substring(string(dataset().date),5,2)",
                                    "date": "@{string(utcnow('yyyy/MM/dd'))}",
                 "dest":"@concat(string(pipeline().parameters.adlFolder),'01')"}
```

and in the dataset i have this:

```
 "folderPath": {
                        "value": "@{dataset().dest}",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
```

Does anybody see what is wrong here? Can i set expressions like this? Thanks a lot for any feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are referencing a dataset's parameter in activity, which is not possible according to my understand.

Activity can only use pipeline's parameters, and dataset can only use dataset's own parameters as well. If you need to use the same value in activity and dataset. I think you will need to specify the parameter both in pipeline and dataset, use pipeline's parameter in pipeline and activity, use datasert's parameter in dataset, then map pipeline's parameter to dataset's paramter in pipeline.

Refer to the examples here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#examples).

For example, use

```
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "BlobDataset",
                    "parameters": {
                        "path": "@pipeline().parameters.inputPath"
                    },
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ],
```

to map pipeline's parameter inputPath to dataset's parameter path. Then use @pipeline().inputPath in activity and @dataset().path in dataset (need to specify them individually in pipeline and dataset).

Comment: yes thats correct. Also expression need to start with @ and everything else (functions,parameters,etc) need to be used without @.
for example @concat(dataset.parameter1,substring(pipeline().parameters.parameter1,2,4).